# Chives have yellowing ends. Is it normal?

Tags: growth, chives

This is the first time I ever grow chives. They are in a seed pod, along with other herb bods in a hydrocultural system (one of those simple amateurish ones sold on Amazon). I planted them 37 days ago. Starting several days ago, I discovered that the end of the scape attached to a black ball of each chive plant is becoming yellow. It seems each chive plant has several scapes (stems), and one of them (usually the shortest one) has a black bead on top (which I assume to be its seed husk). Is it normal that this stem is gradually yellowing and possibly dying? Some taller stems also have yellow tips.

I am worried that there might be something I am not doing right and it might kill all of my chives. The chive shoot that came out earliest died a couple days after it sprouted, leaving me the impression that either I got something wrong in their environment or the plant food, or chives are extremely fragile and sensitive. The rest that sprouted after that one have been fine until recently.

Comment: Chives bloom: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=chive+blossom&t=ffsb&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images  That black bead is likely a bud. It should be green. Not sure about yellow tips. Has the light changed? Chives like their light.